# jQuery, CSS: Animating following DOM Elements after display: none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, display

One quick question.
If I set a div to `display: none`, the following Elements in the DOM will jump up on the place where the div was.
How can I animate that jump, that it just moves gently up?
Thnaks in advance for each help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Instead of display: none; make it with height: 0; and transition: height .5s; overflow: hidden;

Then you will have slightly move of other divs next to others. :)

If you wanna, I can made a simple codepen.

Comment: That'd be nice :)

Comment: Pure CSS: http://codepen.io/bra1N/pen/bwQQOo here you go, just click on red square :)

Comment: No problem, any time :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `slideUp()` instead of `hide();` if you use jquery

```
$('.hidden').slideUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just animate it. jQuery has many ways of doing it, e.g:

```
$('#myDiv').hide(200); // 200ms
```

Comment: @madalinivascu No, i mean jQuery  http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete

Answer (score 0):

To avoid to keep an hidden element with a width that could interfere with other elements on the page, you should simply:

```
$('yourElement').slideUp();
```

That way you will make the `yourElement` height animate and, finally, get it hidden actually removing it from the elements flow.

Edit:
Thanks A. Wolff for the comment. Removed un-needed `.hide()` function after `.slideUp()`.

Comment: No, `hide()` (without duration parameter) won't be pushed in fx queue meaning element will be hidden before slideUp animation completes and anyway it doesn't really make sense because calling both methods is redundant

Comment: Thanks, you are completely right. I am going to correct the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Got even a better solution for you. You can show and hide the blue box with every time you click on the pink box.

```js
$('.pinkBox').click(function() {
  $('.pinkBox').addClass('show');
  $('.blueBox').addClass('displayed');
});

$('.blueBox').click(function() {
  $('.pinkBox').removeClass('show');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.blueBox').removeClass('displayed');
    }, 300);
});
```

```css
.blueBox {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.pinkBox {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  position: absolute;
}
.show {
  transform: translateY(100px);
}
.displayed {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='blueBox'>
</div>

<div class='pinkBox'>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks pretty solid, not what I need for this problem though but a pretty good solution for a bunch of things. Thank you!

Comment: @klvler Animating the `display` is always very problematic. In the most cases it just doesn't work how it is intented to be.

Comment: @klvler I have changed the code a little bit. Added the `display: none` when the blue box is not visible. Check it.